# On The Properties of Proportions: Dealing with sqrt's

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, ratio

For an Analytical Geometry course for 1st years, the book we are following went on to talk about projections after 2D geometry part(topics covered so far: coordinates, transformations, straight line, pair of straight lines and conics). There is a certain lemma I did not understand. It goes as follows:

> Given a straight line,L, through origin, if $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$ are the angle L makes with the 3 axes respectively, then $l=\cos\alpha, m=\cos\beta,n=\cos\gamma$ are L's direction cosines. let $P(x,y,z)$ be any point on L and let OP have measure r.

The text then writes $x=lr,y=mr,z=rn$ which I understand to be due to theorems regarding projections on lines and all. From here, it writes: $\frac{x}{l}=\frac{y}{m}=\frac{z}{n}=r$ which is just the coordinates of a point P in terms of distance OP=r from origin and the direction ratios. Upto this i get. But then the textbook writes something I still dont understand:

let a,b,c be given proportionals to the direction cosines of a line. Then: $$\frac{\cos\alpha}{a}=\frac{\cos\beta}{b}=\frac{\cos\gamma}{c}.....(1)$$
How are we able to write this? What does it mean?
After that they had written $$\frac{\cos\alpha}{a}=\frac{\cos\beta}{b}=\frac{\cos\gamma}{c}=\frac{\sqrt{(\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma)}}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}}.....(2)$$

How are we able to write (2) from (1)? I know these are all proportions, but what am I missing? I haven't seen such a property of proportions before. Is there a proof to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to verify it.

Let $\frac{cos\alpha}{a}=\frac{cos\beta}{b}=\frac{cos\gamma}{c} = k$; for some non-zero constant $k$.

Then, $\cos\alpha = ka$ and $\cos\beta = kb$ and … …

Therefore, $\dfrac {\sqrt{(cos^2\alpha+cos^2\beta+cos^2\gamma)}}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}}
= k = \frac{cos\alpha}{a}=\frac{cos\beta}{b}=\frac{cos\gamma}{c}$

Comment: I see, that's definitely something I hadn't thought of. Also, is this a property that is widely known? I only came across this because of that Analytical Geometry course I took, I could not even find mentions of it online.

Comment: @F.N.1402 Actually, this is a result of a theorem in ratios. See page 4 of Higer algebra by Hall & Knight. Hope you can still find that text.

Comment: Thank you so much. For that book, I will try for a copy online or email a professor to see if they can send me one. Though I did Algebra in highschool before starting my 1st semester courses, it would appear a few theorems get glanced over. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @F.N.1402 The first edition of the book is 1887. It has been revised and reprinted for many years. The one I got is a 1964 version. There should be some newer versions asround.

Comment: Wow, that is a really well established book then. So that is why Analytical Geometry courses use the theorems from such books without much reference, its because back when Analytical Geometry courses were offered as stand alone courses(upto 1960-70's I believe) everyone already knew this theorems. My school is a bit unique then in that sense, as it still offers a standalone course on A.G. very interesting stuff, really.  I see, then it would be better if I write to the Maths department of my school to see its availability in my country. Thanks, once again.